# Javascript Regexp Format

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm a beginner in JavaScript. I tried every tutorial/site and couldn't find an answer. I couldn't understand some examples.

I want to put a specific format and validate if the users input is correct.

Here is my code:

```
var expD = document.getElementById("ccN");

var re = new RegExp("[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]");

if (re.test(expD))
  bootbox.alert("Correct");
else
  bootbox.alert("Wrong");
```

Comment: What is the valid format, add some examples of valid and invalid formats

Comment: [0-9] -Find any digit between the brackets from w3schools.com. iIwant the format to be 00/00

Comment: Can you please add the complete code, jsfiddle will be preferred

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vaughnellis/frbfxg3d/

Comment: Use the `pattern` attribute on the `input` element for validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `expD` is DOMElement, you cannot use it as if it is `string`
2. You need to bind event on textbox/button, to check if the value entered by user is in valid format
3. The regular expression needs `^` and `$` anchors, if you want to check if the complete string is in the valid format

In your case `expD` is a dom element, I think you need to get the value and test it

```js
function testit() {
  var expD = document.getElementById("ccN").value;
  var re = /^\d{2}\/\d{2}$/;
  if (re.test(expD)) {
    alert("Correct");
  } else {
    alert("Wrong");
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="ccN" />
<button onclick="testit()">Test</button>
```

Comment: Thats it? I see many other errors. 1. No eventListener 2. Missing Anchors `^$` 3. bootbox, Huh?

Comment: what's the fix? i want to validate the user input.

Comment: I think you forgot end anchor `$` in regex

Comment: @vaughnellisramos the fix is `document.getElementById("ccN").value`... see the sample